# How to parse a xml from project resources android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, uri

I have a XML file (config.xml) in res/xml folder and I need to parse this XML.
To do this I use SAXParser. I am trying this way:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
          //handler definition...
};
Uri configUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://myPackageName/" + R.xml.config);
saxParser.parse(configXML.toString(), handler);
```

But this doesn't works...

The parse method is have the following parameters:

> uri   The location of the content to be parsed.
>
> dh    The SAXDefaultHandler to use.

Should I use an URI or an Uri? Whats is the difference?

Comment: hi use `XmlResourceParser` instead of `SAXParser` for parsing resources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a XML file (config.xml) in res/xml folder and I need to parse this XML

Call `getResources().getXml(R.xml.config)`. You will be handed an [`XmlResourceParser`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html), which follow the `XmlPullParser` API. As shown in the [`XmlPullParser` JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html), you wind up with code like this:

```
     XmlResourceParser xpp=getResources().getXml(R.xml.config);
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
       if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
           // do something
       } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
           // do something
       } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
           // do something
       } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
           // do something
       }
      eventType = xpp.next();
     }
```

> To do this I use SAXParser

Even if you can get that to work, it will be ~10 times slower than using the `XmlResourceParser`.

Comment: @CommonsWare - Is it possible (runtime within application) to obtain full binary data of AXML (compiled XML) layout?

Comment: @Ωmega: I am not aware of one, but I have not looked for one either.

Comment: @CommonsWare - If you don't know, who knows then? :)) In case you find some way how, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @Ωmega: "If you don't know, who knows then?" -- somebody who is into app decompiling, perhaps. Though one possibility comes to mind: try `openRawResource()` on `Resources`. While the name indicates it is for raw resources, I have seen other SO answers showing it used for other resource types. If you pass a layout resource ID to it, it is possible you will get an `InputStream` on the compiled resource.

Comment: @CommonsWare - I hoped you know some hack how to get those data from `XmlResourceParser` class of `getXml()`.

Comment: @Ωmega: That in particular I would not expect to return the compiled XML of a layout resource. Sorry!